# What should I use 'abbreviate', 'concise' or 'initialize'?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I am looking at some Korean words and realized some of them tend to use making short word such as BLT( A sandwich filled with Bacon, Lettuce and Tomato).

e.g., Ocbesh meaning Octopus + beef intestine + shrimp

In this case, which sentence is correct?

1. They're using abbreviated word.
2. They're using concise word.
3. They're using initialize word.

Comment: @LucianSava You can put your answer into the answer box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, most people would regard 'Ocbesh' as a 'condensed' word - an abreviation is normally used for things like `abrev.`  whereas this conjoins three words into one longish word.

Both 'concise' and 'initialise' mean rather different things, and are not appropriate here, for your 'Ocbesh' example, though 'BLT' is both an abbreviation and an initialism, though the latter term isn't as common.

Comment: *Rd* (Road) and *Dr* (Doctor) are good examples of abbreviations that are not initialisms

Comment: I got what are abbreviate and initialism. So that could be very depends on how words condensed.

Comment: @Smock thanks for informing. It’s clear explanation for me.